# Find the complete factorization of $x^{14}-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was just wondering if anyone could provide me with a solution for the following problem so I can work towards it, it's been a while since I've done a problem like this and it seems my knowledge has started to deteriorate, anyway here is the question.

Find the complete factorization of $x^{14}-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First, we can try to factor it as much as possible:
$$(x^{14}-1) = (x^7-1)(x^7+1)$$
I'll leave factoring $x^7+1$ until the end.
First, lets look at $x^7-1$.
Note that this has a root at $x = 1$, so we get that:
$$(x^{14}-1) = \frac{x^7-1}{x-1}(x-1)(x^7+1)$$
Now, recall the finite geometric sum formula:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^n r^i = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$
Note that $\frac{x^7-1}{x-1} = \sum_{i = 0}^6 x^i = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$ from this formula.
This polynomial is known as a [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), and is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  I'm unsure of an elementary way to show that (I have both an intuitive argument, and a number theoretic one.  The number theoretic one involves Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion, but I'll omit that).

Intuitively, $\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}$ will have roots at all the solutions to $x^7 = 1$ besides $x = 1$. Are there other solutions to this? Not in $\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$ for that matter).  The solutions to this will all have $|x| = 1$, and actually live on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. The solutions will all be of the form $\zeta_7^k$ sufficient $k$.  These will be evenly spaced around the unit circle, and the only time it'll be real is at $\zeta_7^k = 1$.  We're specifically looking for solutions that aren't $1$, so by this heuristic there are none.

Now, consider $x^7+1$.  If we let $y = -x$, we get that:
$$x^7+1 = 0\iff (-y)^7+1 = 0\iff -y^7 +1 = 0\iff y^7 -1=0 $$
We can factor this the same way we factored $x^7-1$ to get that:
$$y^7-1 = (1-y)(1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4+y^5+y^6)$$
Now, substituting back in $y = -x$, we get that:
$$x^7+1 = (1+x)(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+x^6)$$
Both of these factors are irreducible (which may not be obvious).
The right term can't have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$ because if it had some root $r$, then $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$ would have a root $-r$, which we've already argued is false.

So, we get that:
$$x^{14}-1 = (x+1)(x-1)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^5)(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+x^6)$$
Where each part of this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Hi thank you for this clear response it makes a load more sense now, so thanks for that, just a quick question on esienstiens irreducibility, would you check that $(x^7-1)$ and $(x^7+1)$ both satisfy the conditions or would we be able to use the method directly without splitting it up?

Comment: Define $\Phi_p(x) = \frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$ for a prime $p$.  Note that we were working with $\Phi_7(x)$ above.  This is the cyclotomic polynomial mentioned above. We can now look at $\Phi_p(x+1) = \frac{(x+1)^p-1}{x}$.  This is just $\Phi_p$ translated by $1$, so will be irreducible if $\Phi_p$ is.  Now, applying the binomial expansion we get that:
$$\Phi_p(x+1) = \frac{\sum_{k = 0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}x^k-1}{x}$$
Now, we note that $p\mid\binom{p}{k}$ for all $k$ except $k = 0,k = p$.  So, we can rewrite this as: $$\Phi_p(x+1) = \sum_{k = 1}^p\binom{p}{k}x^{p-1}$$ We can apply Eisenstein's to this.

Comment: so you would just check that the cyclomatic polynomial satisfies esienstiens irreducibility test for each case which in turn will prove that they are irreducible over Q?